# Получить уровень вложенности

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image]
У меня есть таблица категорий, каждая имеет:
**id, parent_id, name**

Мне нужно написать функцию (скорее всего рекурсивную), которая берет массив с этими категориями, и разбивает на уровни.

```
function get_level_categories($level = 0)
{
    $result = array();
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $categories = $ci->cms_base->get_categories();
    foreach($categories as $cat => $key) {
        echo($cat.$key.'<br/>');
    }

    //return $result;
}
```

В функции мне нужно указать только уровень, в данном случае, если я в view'ере укажу $it = get-level-categories(3), он мне должен вывести массив из YH112,YH11-2,YH11-3,YH11, и другие категории которые будут находится в 3ем уровне.
Как такое реализовать:?

Comment: Если у вас есть код который реализовывает чтение всего и сразу - опубликуйте пожалуйста. По сути вам просто нужно добавить фильтр

Comment: Не совсем понял. Но думаю, вы об этом:
`$categories = $ci->cms_base->get_categories();` Этот код читает всё и сразу (получат полный массив категорий), фильтр я пытался организовать в foreach, но пока не знаю, как правильно это сделать.

Comment: Ну, например, я CI уже с год не видел, выложите пожалуйста **код**

Comment: public function get_categories()
     {
      $this->db->order_by('position', 'ASC');
      $query = $this->db->get('category');

      if ($query->num_rows() > 0 )
      {
       $categories = $query->result_array();

                ($hook = get_hook('cmsbase_return_categories')) ?eval($hook) : NULL; 
            
                return $categories;
      }

      return FALSE;
      }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если массив категорий `$categories` индексирован по `$id`, то уровень можно получить через циклический подъем вверх по дереву до корневого узла:

```
function getLevel(&$categories, $id)
{
    $level = 0;
    while( $id = $categories[$id]['parent_id'] ) $level++;
    return $level;
}
```

**UPD:** Для массива строк из базы `$level` для указанного `$id` можно посчитать так:

```
function getLevel(&$categories, $id)
{
    $level = 0;
    while( $id ){
        $index = null;
        foreach( $categories as $i => $row){
            if( $row['id'] == $id ){
                $index = $i;
                break;
            }
        }
        $id = null;
        if( $index !== null ){
            $id = $categories[$index]['parent_id'];
            if( $id ) $level++;
        }
    }
    return $level;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению $categories индексирована от 0 до n, поэтому этот метод не подходит

Comment: @chuikoff, да, ты прав. Результат запроса именно таким и будет. Смотри UPD.

Comment: Спасибо. К сожалению, я изначально вопрос не правильно задал, это пока не решило мою задачу но приблизило решение, может сам дальше справлюсь.

Comment: Чтобы получить список категорий с нужным `$level` функцию `getLevel` можно пропустить через цикл. Если оформить это все в виде функции, то получится:

    function getCatByLevel(&$categories, $level)
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach( $categories as $row ){
            if( getLevel($categories, $row['id']) == $level )
                $result[] = $row;
        }
        return $result;
    }