# Как узнать максимальную вложенность элементов массива php?

Tags: php, массивы

Допусим, есть рандомный php массив:

```
$array = [[1, 2],[2, 3, [3, 4]], [[2, [3, [a, b]], [2, 5]], [2, 6, 3]]];
```

Каким образом узнать уровень максимально вложеннего элемента?
Т.е. вложенность сейчас - 4 уровень, это элементы [a, b];

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/96657/186083 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511681/186083

Comment: @entithat пробовал, не пойму как написать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Главное, что нам понадобиться, это - [`is_array()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-array.php).

```
$array = [[1, 2],[2, 3, [3, 4]], [[2, [3, [0, 0]], [2, 5]], [2, 6, 3]]];

function get_lvl(array $array) {
    $max_lvl = 1;

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $lvl= get_lvl($value) + 1;

            if ($lvl> $max_lvl) {
                $max_lvl = $lvl;
            }
        }
    }

    return $max_lvl;
}

echo get_lvl($array);
```

[Спасибо за помощь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262891/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-how-deep-a-php-array-is) [**@Other**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/207618/other), но суть решения задачи остаётся прежней:)

Comment: ОК, тогда добавьте один массив в корень массива и узрите неправильность!

Comment: Скопируйте отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/q/262891/6275986

Comment: Да, мне нужен уровень вложенности. Я a, b указал для примера - они самые глубокие элементы в массиве.

Comment: @Other да, ваше решение помогло. Спасибо большое! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262891/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-how-deep-a-php-array-is

Comment: @azhirov1991, Всегда пожалуйста.

Comment: @Other, надеюсь это был не сарказм с Вашей стороны:))) Ответ обновил и скопировал по Вашему совету. Да, забыл учесть, что мой прежний код считал даже тогда, когда вышел из вложенного массива. И к тому же изменил название переменных, чтобы было легче понять:)

Answer (score 1):

> *Каким образом узнать уровень максимально вложеннего элемента? Т.е. вложенность сейчас - 4 уровень*

Можно использовать метод `getDepth()` класса [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php):

```
$array = [[1, 2],[2, 3, [3, 4]], [[2, [3, ['a', 'b']], [2, 5]], [2, 6, 3]]];

echo get_depth($array);
```

Результат: `4`

```
function get_depth(Array $arr, $depth = 0): Int
{
    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));

    foreach ($it as $tmp) {
        $int = $it->getDepth();
        $depth >= $int ?: $depth = $int;
    }

    return $depth;
}
```