# Почему я могу вывести отдельные элементы массива но не могу сам массив через var_dump()?

Tags: php, modx

Этот код пишу в снипете Modx.

почему так работает?

```
$myconfig = $modx->getConfig();

var_dump($myconfig['dbname']);
var_dump($myconfig['password']);
var_dump($myconfig['username']);
```

(именованные элементы массива выводятся без проблем),
а вот так:

```
$myconfig = $modx->getConfig();
var_dump($myconfig);
```

...НЕ работает (я получаю пустую страницу, при этом код PHP на ней вообще не выполняется)?

Массив создается - 100% - я проверял через isset(), и индексы массива выводятся, а сам массив не выводится.

Логика подсказывает мне только одну причину - возможно, есть какие-то ограничения, а сам массив не маленький.

Только чьи это ограничения - PHP  или Modx?

Comment: потому что скорее всего array access и $myconfig - это не массив а объект. А пустая страница - потому что там в этом конфиге столько наворочено что пхп падает с ошибкой.

Comment: все бы ничего, но в логах никаких сообщений об ошибках нет :(

Comment: А ошибки вообще в логе бывают?  gettype() и вардамп для $myconfig что выдают?

Comment: вардамп, как написано изначально - нифига не выдает, геттайп выдает "эррэй"

Comment: что выдает count() и array_keys() ?

Comment: каунт выдает 376, эррэй_кейс выводит ключи.

Comment: Вывода нет потому что ошибка рекурсия какая-нибудь. Ошибки нету потому что не настроен о логирование

Comment: не настроен на логирование кто? Пых, Модекс или Апач?

Comment: падает у тебя пхп, а не модх или апач

Comment: согласен, логика тут есть...
может увеличить объем памяти для ПХП?
там вроде есть такая опция в конфиге...

Comment: Может. Но увеличивать объем памяти надо не потому что у тебя левая пятка зачесалась, а в том случае **если её не хватает**. Чтобы узнать, хватает ли памяти, надо посмотреть сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    // в начало файла
    
    //и попробуй так
    $myconfig = $modx->getConfig();
    print_r($myconfig);
    echo"<br>";
    foreach ($myconfig as $key => $value) {
      # code...
    print_r($key);
  echo"<br>";
    print_r($value);
    echo"<br>";

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: $key вперёд, чтобы понять, на каком упало

Comment: не, не взлетело: пустая страница получилась.
Я даже принт_р общий не ставил - знаю что не сработает, только один цикл оставил, все равно "слегло".

Comment: массив где то косячит

Comment: echo implode('|', $value); попробуй так в цикле сделать, преобразовав в строку

Comment: oreach ($myconfig as $key => $value) {
      # code...
   echo implode('|', $value); 
  echo"<br>";

Comment: Вы извините, но я вот насчет имплода все-равно не могу понять, зачем его в цикл вкладывать, если он и так должен весь массив в одну строку сложить....
Но... зато я попробовал прогнать массив через gettype(), и увидел, что там есть несколько вложенных массивов. 
Предполагаю, что именно тут собака порылась...

Comment: странная все-таки шняга...
Исключил в цикле массивы на вывод таким условием: if (gettype ($value) != "array") {...},
условие работает - проверил, НО это все-равно не помогло!
Даже те элементы массива, которые НЕ являются вложенными массивами тоже не хотят выводиться ;(

Comment: Я сразу понял что у тебя есть вложенность

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/812308/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-php